# Do "liver spots" ever scab up and peel off

Tags: coloration-discoloration, hand, scab, shape-form-pattern

I have had a liver spot o my left hand about the size of a dime for many years, at least 10 and more likely 20. A few weeks ago it started to change appearance, at first appearing to turn a darker shade of brown with a scabby texture, with a slight reddish-tinged border. I saw my GP and have been referred to a specialist, apt in July. A size measurement was taken, and I was instructed not to worry before July unless the spot starts growing.

However since then it has completely scabbed over and peeled off. The residual spot is the same size and shape as the original but much paler, almost my natural skin tone. Can anyone explain this? I was expecting these spots to start getting darker and more prominent, not lighter and less prominent.